# Can not pass error via delegate

Tags: c#, .net

Can not pass error via delegate...

**ERROR:**

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

**CODE:**

```
 RssReader.GetRssItems(IsUsePlainText,
                                  url, ShowImages,
                                  items =>
                                  {
                                      if (items.Any())
                                      {
                                          DataRSS.AddRange(items);
                                      }
                                  }, error => {

                                      var s = error.Message; // Nothing is go here... :(
                                  }
                                            , OnFinally);



public static void GetRssItems(bool isUsePlainText, string rssFeedUrl, bool showImages, 
            Action<IEnumerable<RssFeedItem>> onGetRssItemsCompleted = null,
            Action<Exception> onError = null, Action onFinally = null)
{

  var webClient = new WebClient();

  webClient.OpenReadCompleted += delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
     try
     {
        if (e.Error != null) // report error
        {
            if (onError != null)
            {
                 onError(e.Error);
            }
            return;
         }

         var stream = e.Result;
         var response = XmlReader.Create(stream); 
         var feeds = SyndicationFeed.Load(response); // When something is wrong here an exception occurs

         // do other stuff...

}
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   onError(ex); // ERROR HAPPENS HERE.... "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
   return;

 }
 finally
 {
   if (onFinally != null)
   {
      onFinally();
   }
}
```

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: You're passing in a null `onError`; you should do a similar `!= null` check like you do earlier in your code. EDIT: Also consider if it's null, to possibly throw the error up rather than silently failing (unless that's your intent)

Comment: You have 306 questions, of which at a glance quite some look like a compilation or runtime error. I'd say that by now you should be able to debug such basic issues yourself, we are not your debugger. The error is pretty clear, onError is null, which you would have seen if you put a breakpoint on that line and inspected the variable. It is null because the calling code obviously passes a null.

Comment: @CodeCaster I respect your ++++ but don't be an evil man... :)

Comment: I'm not trying to be evil (I haven't killed any puppies for example, at least not that I know of), but I strongly advise to show some research effort for your questions. Then not only will you find that people are more helpful, but also you might even be able to solve such problems yourself.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah... and now I have got 2 things: my question has -4  and there is no solution still... Cool...

Comment: The first comment gave you an answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster It doesn't ....

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Could u please put some code like an example but have a look at mu updated question initially, please ?

Comment: @CodeCaster 306 questions.... Hmmm U ARE EVIL!!!! :) I will ASK always by using C# and .Net tags and it will bother u ... I know... hahahhahaa

Comment: It bothers me so much, I think I cannot sleep tonight. Good luck anyway. :-)

Comment: Did you set VisualStudio to break on all errors? Your breakpoint is at the start of the `catch`, not where you're calling `onError`.

Comment: @JonB I have tried all places to put breakpoints...

Comment: @JonB Have I create somehow Action<Exception> onError = ????  inside of the method? I am completely stuck with it.

Comment: I have no idea. You haven't updated your code, you just posted a partial screenshot. I don't even know what error you're getting now.

Comment: @Peretz You had problems in your code that was throwing an `XmlException`, in the `try/catch` handler for it, you in turn threw a _second_ error (the `NullReferenceException`) when you tried to report the _first_ error. The problem you are seeing now is likely in `var feeds = SyndicationFeed.Load(response)` which is a _separate issue entirely_ from what this question started as. The two answers here are correct for your original question (mark one). Start debugging your XML loading issues (not error handling), and if you have issues with that, post a new question with relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do same null-check as you did when invoked action first time:

```
catch (Exception ex)
 { 
    if (onError != null)
        onError(ex); 
   return;    
 }
```

If you want to avoid null-checks - attach dummy handler to `Action` delegate at the top of your method:

```
onError += (e) => {};
```

Comment: Thank you! Could u have a look at the my top level method and suggest where I can apply your solution, please?

Comment: Thank you! I have read this cool article http://seankerwin.org/archives/2009/10/asynchronicity_in_c_error_hand.shtml and put (exception) =>{
                                   var i = exception.Message;
                               } to the top level method and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `onError` is null.

Change to:

```
if (onError != null) onError(ex);
```

Or, perform some other action if the caller fails to pass in a delegate.

Comment: Yes but why? How to fix it?

Comment: When you call `GetRssItems`, be sure to pass in a delegate. And check for null before trying to call it.

Comment: @JonB why? delegated seems to be optional parameter

Comment: As an optional parameter, the caller may or may not supply a value. If no value is supplied, the default is used (in this case, null). When you try to invoke `onError`, you're assuming it is non null. It will be null if the caller did not supply a value, or if the caller actually passed in null.

Comment: @JonB you said `be sure to pass in a delegate` - that's not true for optional parameters. Check for null - yes. Pass in - not

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't work... Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - my point was more that if you want a delegate, pass one in. Obviously, since it's optional you don't have to.